# Excel Conditional Formula to evaluate multiple column ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Apologies, If the solution is already available, I have been searching for hours!

The problem I am facing is that to put conditional formula based on column ranges for e.g:

```
Conditions:

1) A1=0, B1=0, C1=0, D1=0 = Result Last Four columns are zero
2) A1=1, B1=0, C1=0, D1=0 = Result Last Three columns are zero
3) A1=1, B1=1, C1=0, D1=0 = Result Last Two columns are zero
4) A1=1, B1=1, C1=1, D1=0 = Result Last column is zero
5) A1=0, B1=0, C1=1, D1=0 = Result Last column is zero
6) A1=0, B1=1, C1=0, D1=0 = Result Last Two columns are zero
7) A1=0, B1=0, C1=0, D1=1 = Result Last Column is Not Empty
```

The catch in the above results is that the condition should consider the column zeros from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Create a named range (I will call it `Sentences`) to store the hardcoded sentences you want as a result. Below is an example (do not include the header in the named range):

| Hardcoded sentences |
| --- |
| Four columns are zero |
| Last Column is Not Empty |
| Three columns are zero |
| First two columns are zero |
| Three columns are zero |
| Two columns are zero |
| Two columns are zero |
| One column is zero |
| Three columns are zero |
| Two columns are zero |
| Two columns are zero |
| One column is zero |
| Last Two columns are zero |
| One column is zero |
| Last column is zero |
| No column is zero |

2. Apply this array formula (to be validated using Ctrl+Shift+Enter):
   `=INDEX(Sentences, 1+SUM(2^(COLUMNS(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1:D1))*(A1:D1<>0)))`

Explanation: the formula counts empty cells as bits (weights: 1, 2, 4, 8), adds the bits together to create and `index` then look into the named range the sentence at the calculated `index`.

Obviously, you will have to edit the values from the named range if the values I typed do not suit your need.

---

Edit:
You can also handle only special cases in the range and leave the general case to a more generic formula.
By special cases, I mean things like "Last column is not empty" (only applies to the last column) as opposed to "One column is zero". (applies to all columns).

You can just leave some cells of the named range empty whenever it is a general case and let the formula below do the job.

```
=IF(
LEN(INDEX(Sentences, 1+SUM(2^(COLUMNS(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1:D1))*(A1:D1<>0)))) > 0,
INDEX(Sentences, 1+SUM(2^(COLUMNS(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1:D1))*(A1:D1<>0))),
INDEX({"All columns are zero","Three columns are zero","Two columns are zero","1 column is zero"}, 1+COUNT(IF(A1:D1=0,1)))
)
```

Comment: Hi Atmo, I have tried the above solution, it is giving #VALUE!

Comment: Most likely because you have validated as a normal formula instead of an array formula.

Comment: I have converted into array formula but it is working for condition 1 and 6 whereas remaining conditions are showing #REF! or incorrect sentence.
The formula needs to read the zeros from right to left i.e. Column D to column A

Comment: About the `#REF!` error, try to put this bit `1+SUM(2^(4-COLUMN(A1:D1))*(A1:D1<>0))` as a separate array formula. You should see the result is always between 1 and 16. Please provide the values for which the longer formula returns `#REF!`. My guess is that something is wrong with the way you configured the named range `Sentences`.

Comment: Regarding the incorrect sentence, it is up to you to adjust the table for every value returned by the small bit of formula in my previous comment. Last, the formula reads all 4 cells at once, it is your misconception the order in which cells are read matters; in fact it does not.

Comment: Yes the result is below 16, but if you see the conditions in question, the formula is working for the first and sixth condition i.e. 'Last four columns are zero' and 'Last Two Columns are Zero', but for condition 2,3, 4 and 7 it is showing #REF! and for condition 5 it is showing 'Two columns are zero' instead it should return 'Last column is zero'

Comment: What is the number you get for condition 5?

Comment: Condition 5 is A5=0, B5=0, C5=1, D5=0, therefore the return value should be 'Last Column is Zero'

Comment: That is not what I ask. I ask what number the formula above returns for condition 5.

Comment: I have removed a hardcoded value in the formula, suggest you copy it again.

Comment: Got it, the number for condition 5 is 3

Comment: Value `3` looks correct, however the 3rd line in the table I posted is `Three columns are zero` (which as I understand, you will have to adjust yourself in the table). If what you are getting is `Two columns are zero`, that means you made a mistake somewhere else; like I said before either when naming the range or on the range content itself.

Comment: Sorry for taking long, the formula provided is looking for zeros in any column but the query I have raised that it should always consider the latest zero from right to left which mean if column A, B and D has 0 and column C has 1 then it should consider only 'column D zero' and ignore column A and B zeros, therefore, the result should be 'Last Column is Zero'.

Comment: You have 4 cells hence 2^4 = 16 cases. I gave you a method to map those 16 cases to 16 cells of a range (each case is numbered by `1+SUM(2^(COLUMNS(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1:D1))*(A1:D1<>0))`). I am repeating for the last time, if I set up the cells incorrectly **YOU** have to adjust their content yourself because you have not provided an exhaustive list. This is but trivial/short effort; I am not going to do it for you, no need to ask again.

Comment: Thank you so much Atmo, the query is working great, I have understood the whole mechanism of your formula from your last comment.